# Not able to create HIT with same layout ir on amazon mturk

Tags: mechanicalturk

I have designed layout on amazon mturk sandbox requester. I used that layoutID to create HIT through my java API.
HIT created for first time but now second time while i am trying to create hit it is giving me following error.

Error executing operation: Error #1 for RequestId: 915ade2b-15dc-4086-b9eb-338a1c7adfed - AWS.MechanicalTurk.PermissionDenied: This user is not authorized to perform the requested operation.

I varified the accesskey and secret_key it is correct now i don't understand whats going wrong ?

Comment: Are you trying to create the HIT on the live server? If you created the template in the sandbox, the LayoutId is specific to the sandbox; you would need to recreate the layout in the live server and then pull its server-specific LayoutId.

Comment: no i am doing it in sandbox only.

Comment: and i am getting this error many times during perform other operations like creating  basic freetext question. I don't know what can be the reason behind it.

Comment: You may want to ask on the developer forum: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=11 or contact AWS directly.